# Inner join 2 count statements

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble joining two count statements, whats throwing me off is that the teamids are different

```
SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS homescore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 1 AND gameid = 1
SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS awayscore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 2 AND gameid = 1
```

*query 1 result*

```
homescore
    0
```

*query 2 result*

```
awayscore
    0
```

what im trying to achieve

```
homescore | awayscore
    0     |     0
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: its for a sports app, each query counts the number of rows in the table thus displaying a score (hometeam vs awayteam), both of these queries on their own achieve what I want but I am trying to do is get it down to 1 query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe this:

```
SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS homescore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 1 AND gameid = 1
union
SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS awayscore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 2 AND gameid = 1
```

**EDIT**: to bring back columns and take care of null values.

```
select  nvl((SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS score FROM goals WHERE teamid = 1 AND gameid = 1),0) as homescore,
        nvl((SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS score FROM goals WHERE teamid = 2 AND gameid = 1),0) as awayscore
from dual
```

Comment: totally forgot about unions, just ran it in phpmyadmin though and it only returned homescore

Comment: it might do that if team 2 didnt score.

Comment: shouldnt it return 0 or null though? just added fake data.... only getting the homescore still

Comment: aah, maybe you need union all if both scores are 1. Try my answer below. It should work in all circumstances.

Comment: union all returns two rows of data in 1 column, instead of 1 row in 2 columns

Comment: union will do that too if there are different numbers of goals scored

Comment: Jas your query seems to accomplish what i am looking for

Comment: Not in this situation as it seems the union was grouping the number 1 and not omitting the line like i thought.

Comment: @user934902  I added another way to query for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I THINK this is what your looking for.

```
select 
sum(case when teamid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as homescore,
sum(case when teamid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as awayscore
from goals where gameid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join or union

SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS homescore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 1 AND gameid = 1 UNION SELECT COUNT(teamid) AS awayscore FROM goals WHERE teamid = 2 AND gameid = 1